# Node.js HTTPS error (SSL_ERROR_NO_CYPHER_OVERLAP) - no common encryption algorithm(s)

Tags: https, openssl, node.js, rhel7, self-signed-certificate

I have seen other similar questions but non addresses my problem. I have generated my TLS (openSSL) Self-Signed certificate, but seems not working on my `NodeJS` server.

**Instructions to generate SSL**

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout key.pem -x509 -days 365 -out certificate.pem

openssl x509 -text -noout -in certificate.pem

openssl pkcs12 -inkey key.pem -in certificate.pem -export -out certificate.p12

openssl pkcs12 -in certificate.p12 -noout -info  // verify certificate
```

So at the end I have `.p12` also known as `PFX` type certificate. Below is my **Node.js** code:

```
    // ------- Start HTTPS configuration ----------------

const options = {

    pfs: fs.readFileSync('./server/security-certificate/certificate.p12'),     
    passphrase: 'secrete2'
};
https.createServer(options, app).listen(8443);


    // -------- End HTTPS configuration -----------------

    // Also listen for HTTP 
var port = 8000;
app.listen(port, function(){
    console.log('running at localhost: '+port);
});
```

Here is the output when I run `curl` command, the HTTP request is served correctly, only HTTPS has problem:

[image: Output when tested on same machine]

Moreover, if I do this:

```
export CURL_CA_BUNDLE=/var/www/html/node_app/server/security-certificate/cert.p12
```

Then I get following error:
`curl: (77) Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)`

If I try to access in browser with HTTPS and port, browser says it could not load the page.

> Reference links I followed:
> Node.js HTTPS:
>
> https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/https.html#https_https_createserver_options_requestlistener
>
> I'm using AWS RedHat Linux

Comment: Please use wireshark/tshark and add to the question decoded tls packets.

Comment: I have shared problem of same linux machine, which could not access itself. I could not install `wireshark` on my live linux machine.

Comment: What version of Node.js is this? What Linux distribution is it?

Comment: Using `node v6.14.2` and OS prettyName is `Amazon Linux AMI 2018.03` with ID Like `Red Hat 7.2.1-2 (rhel fedora)`

Comment: [The option key is **spelled `pfx` not `pfs`**](https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_tls_createsecurecontext_options) Also the file you give the _client_ (curl) should be the certificate alone not the P12; I believe curl/NSS accepts CAcert in PEM (curl/openssl definitely does).

Comment: I deleted my answer :)